# Can't solve Javascript error Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method 'get' of underfined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

This is using the JavaScript JDK for parse.com

Please note that this code is is based on backbone.js framework, which lets you ebed script tags into your html 5 code.

Using a parse.com class I'm storing 2 objects "Global_Badges_img" and "text". I want my query to cycle through the data and where it finds records in either of the above objects I want it to be able to display it eventually in html.

I got the query working correctly for images, it cycles through and pulls out 6 images.

I then replicated the code for "text", but I'm getting the error shown in the screen shot.

What is causing this? Can I not set the query to run like this? It looks like "text" has not been defined, but I'm unsure what I have missed.

I cannot find an exact match to this issue on SO or Google.

jfiddle set up here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/DJ9VU/

Code being used is below. Error! picture is attached

```
var GlobalBadges = Parse.Object.extend("Global_Badges");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GlobalBadges);
    query.exists("Global_Badges_img");
    query.exists("text");
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        text = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];
          imageURLs.push(object.get('Global_Badges_img'));
          text.push(object.get('text'));
        }

        $('#Image01').attr('src',imageURLs[0]); //first image
        $('#Image02').attr('src',imageURLs[1]); //second image
        $('#Image03').attr('src',imageURLs[2]); //third image
        $('#Image04').attr('src',imageURLs[0]); //first image
        $('#Image05').attr('src',imageURLs[1]); //second image
        $('#Image06').attr('src',imageURLs[2]); //third image
        console.log(object.get('text'));
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
```

Comment: My guess would be that some members of `results` are `undefined`. I'm not familiar enough with parse.com to help you any further.

Comment: Thanks, so the actual code looks correct?

Comment: Well, the object in `console.log` might be `undefined`, if the `results` array is empty. I don't know if this is possible. Otherwise it looks correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Obviously you should test for `undefined`, if empty indexes are "normal".

Comment: @sabof if you add these as an answer I will accept it as it helped me trap an issue in the back end

Comment: @Danno007 I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my thoughts after reading the code, and being unfamiliar with parse.com. a) Some members of `results` could be `undefined`. b) Should `results` happen to be an empty array, there would be an error on the line with `console.log`.